# Oracle in hyper-convergence system

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

How does Oracle perform in hyperconvergence systems such as nutanix, simplivity? Oracle doesn't certify the underlying storage which nutanix or simplivity offers (file level storage) but in reality case studies say those systems perform good in general but with Oracle databases, technically how sound it is to go ahead with it?